# How to get Child state by ref in parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'am begginer in React-Native and I'am trying to make a sudoku game.
I encounter an issue.
I want to change the state of my Cell Component in my Play Component, which is his GranParent. In fact what I want is when I touch a cell it will be highlight if it is not fixed. I was thinking doing with his ref, that is set in the Grid component, but I don't know how I can do it.

Thanks for your help!

```
 class Cell extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: this.props.number,
      highlight: false,
      fixed: false,
      filled:false
      
    }

    this.setHighlight = this.setHighlight.bind(this)
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this)
  }
  

  setHighlight(highlight) {
    this.setState({
      highlight: highlight,
    });
  }

  onPress = (e) => {
    this.props.onPress && this.props.onPress(this.props.index, this.state.number, this.state.fixed);
  }

  render() {
    const { number, fixed, highlight} = this.state;

    const filled = typeof(number) == 'number';
    const text = filled ? number : '';
    return (
      <View style={[styles.cell, filled&&styles.filledCell, fixed&&styles.fixedCell, highlight&&styles.highlightCell]} >
        {
          <Text style={[styles.text, fixed&&styles.fixedText, highlight&&styles.highlightText]}>{text}</Text>
        }
        <Touchable activeOpacity={fixed?1:0.8} onPress={this.onPress} style={styles.handle} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Grid extends Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.cells = []
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
      {
        stack.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <View key={'grid' + i} style={styles.grid} >
            {
              stack.map((item, j) => {
                const x = i % 3 * 3 + j % 3;
                const y = Math.floor(i / 3) * 3 + Math.floor(j / 3);
                const index = x + y * 9;
                return (<Cell ref={ref => this.cells[index] = ref} key={'cell' + index} 
                  index={index} number={sudoku.sudoku[index].answer} onPress={this.props.onPress} />)
              })
            }
            </View>
          )
        })
      }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Play extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            number:null,
           }
        
    }

    
    onCellPress(index, number, fixed) {
    
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View styel={styles.container}>
                <Grid onPress = {this.onCellPress}/>
                <Widget />
                <Number />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You can set it in the child directly.

So when you call

```
<Touchable activeOpacity={fixed?1:0.8} onPress={this.onPress} style={styles.handle} />
```

In:

```
  onPress = (e) => {
    this.props.onPress && this.props.onPress(this.props.index, this.state.number, this.state.fixed);
    // Set the state here that you want
    this.setState({...state, highlighted: state.fixed ? false : !state.highlighted});
  }
```

However, if you are trying to actually change this from the parent because the parent needs to know something about the child's state and change it manually, it's time to lift that state up! I'd read this [guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) in the docs and this is the actual [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) on lifting state up.

What you'd do is take that state out of the cell and put it in the grandparent as an array of objects or an object whose property is objects. Then the parent can modify that state directly and pass it down to child / grandchild.

An example would be a cool display that shows a timer and a button that resets the timer, which are different components. The parent would contain both of those components and it would hold the value of the timer and pass it down to the component that displays it.

I would not use a `ref`. This is an anti-pattern in react and there are plenty of stack overflow posts about it. Here is their [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs) on it.

> Your first inclination may be to use refs to “make things happen” in
> your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically
> about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy. Often,
> it becomes clear that the proper place to “own” that state is at a
> higher level in the hierarchy. See the Lifting State Up guide for
> examples of this.

And if you find state is getting lifted too high, passed around too much, and used all over your app... time for the [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API.

Honestly, my work flow is often put state as low as I can. Then I re-factor and lift it up (doesn't take long) when I realize I was wrong. Then when it gets used everywhere, I move it to a context. Better planning could probably avoid these refactors, but I find it works for me.

Comment: I will check the documentation about lifting state up, seems to be what I need. Thanks!